# How can I float elements with different size in a tile

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

The question is simple. I have a bunch of elements that are going to make a tile. However, some of them have a longer height; let's say twice as much as the other ones. I want all of them to match in a tile just by pure CSS styling.

Here is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px black inset;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#d1,
#d2,
#d4,
#d5,
#d6,
#d8,
#d9{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#d7,
#d3{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d1">1</div><div id="d2">2</div><div id="d3">3</div><div id="d4">4</div><div id="d5">5</div><div id="d6">6</div><div id="d7">7</div><div id="d8">8</div><div id="d9">9</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And you can try it live on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/usovek/1/edit

**Notes:**

- The content is dynamic
- The number of boxes can vary
- Any box can be longer. And possibly wider.
- The width or height of boxes are always a number of units. The unit in this example is 50 and some boxes are 50, some others are 100px high. But It would be perfect if the problem is solved for any number of units (1,2,3... which are 50px, 100px, 150px,...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your content is static, you can use position absolute blocks inside a relatively positioned container, but if the content is dynamic than you cannot do this with CSS(Only), what you need to use is

[**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Or the best you can do is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/PvdVF/)

CSS

```
#d7,
#d3{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

3rd Possibility:
Wrap the boxes insde containers and float the accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3b6k/1/) (Only Possible When Things Are Static) :)

Comment: thanks for the link to JQuery Masonry. It's absolutely fantastic. However, I prefer to do it with pure CSS if possible. Also I like your CSS solution even though it changes the order of elements. If no one else comes with a better solution that is pure CSS and with the right order, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @AlexStack I'll make a pure CSS example for you, but wont be the way you;ve stacked your elements :)

Comment: "3rd Possibility: Wrap the boxes insde containers and float the accordingly". I didn't understand. Can you provide some example code please?

Comment: @AlexStack Yup that's what I am doing :)

Comment: thanks. I also have a problem with your earlier solution. If I add a couple of more boxes, they don' fill the space that is created on the left side of the floated element: http://jsfiddle.net/PvdVF/1/

Comment: well, it seems the latter solution combines presentation with structure (the "float_left" class names, inline styles or extra containers). It makes it harder to generate the code dynamically. But nevertheless, I guess I understand now how to achieve the goal. Thanks anyway. I'll accept this answer if no one comes up with a better solution.

Comment: @AlexStack Even I'll be amazed if someone came up with a better solution ;)