# Bootstrap span, row, column elements need to line them up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new here and to Bootstrap so apologies for any stupidity.

In Bootstrap I'm trying to display `.span4` in a row over 2 columns, this is because of page width, which should eventually nest into each other and leave no space. However with all I have tried at the moment I can still only manage to get each `.span4` to lineup with the bottom-line of the longest span4 I have created. The site will eventually be dynamic and the size of the list could change frequently.

Looked at many different questions on here but no joy yet.

I have an example of my tryings here http://jsfiddle.net/joebarr/YJunh/

Comment: Is your question related with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css? If not, could you explain with an example (an image or whatever) your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). See for example: [How can I float elements with different size in a tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320160/how-can-i-float-elements-with-different-size-in-a-tile) or [How to Create Grid/Tile View with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470070/how-to-create-grid-tile-view-with-css)

In case it must be CSS only, the accepted answer for the first link above ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320187/1449799 ) shows a good approximation.